# Android InputManagerService Starting input on non-focused client

Tags: android, service, android-input-method

In my logcat I found some warning message

InputManagerService

```
Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40651cb0 (uid=10015 pid=3024)
```

ActivityManager

```
Process com.android.inputmethod.latin (pid 3034) has died.
Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME in 5000ms
Low Memory: No more background processes.
```

InputDispatcher

```
channel '40827098 com.vigorshine.zsafe/com.vigorshine.zsafe.Main02 (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8

channel '40827098 com.vigorshine.zsafe/com.vigorshine.zsafe.Main02 (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's the problem of Memory leak by custom bitmap and typeface.
I need to recycle and setCallBack(null) to release them.